# How to make API abstraction layer code cleaner

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest

### Introduction

I'm developing a react application that has to communicate with a rest api. Currently the full api isn't fully implemented yet, so I'm making mock ups and to avoid wasted code I'm adding an adding an abstraction layer between mock up/api and application.

### Current situation

Currently I have classes representing the components (like 'a user') in the api. A get request of an url `obj1/obj2/ob3/` is translated into javascript as `server.get("obj1").get("obj2").get("obj3").fetch(...args).then(onsucces,onerror)`.
`fetch` would return a promise. the other methods

### The question

My question has 2 parts.
First is there a way to clean up this part, `.get("obj1").get("obj2").get("obj3")`. (I don't think react supports Proxies).

Secondly, if you have recursive requests

```
server.get("user").get(<id>).fetch(
    (user)=>{
        update_ui(user);
        user.books.fetch(
            (books)=>{
                update_ui(books);
            },(error)=>{}
        )
    },(error)=>{}
)
```

they can get ugly quickly, is there a way similar to `.then(...).then(...)` (for promises) to flatten them or something complete differently that would result in better code.

### What `get().get()...fetch()` does

the gets would construct a path from which the fetch,... operations will be executed for an actual api these would be urls for a mock-up this could be a hard-coded dictionary.

for example, `get("users").get(<userid>)`, would correspond to an object of the form

```
{
    path:"users.<userid>" //(or any other seperator)
    fetch: function(...args)  //GET specified in the api
    push: null // api doesn't specify a POST request for this url
    ...
}
```

the translation of HTTP request to javascript is as follows:

- GET to `fetch`
- POST to `push`
- PUT to `set`
- PATCH to  `update`
- DELETE to `pop`

the implementation of these methods (`fetch`) would then use the `path` and the specified arguments to get,post,... the data.

Comment: Without seeing how those methods you're using operate, it's hard to say - a fix for cleaner code here, if any, would require a change to the code for those methods

Comment: Coding react is not similar to coding nodejs :) Colud you please explain what is returned from `server.get("obj1").get("obj2").get("obj3")`?

Comment: Does this provide a better explanation?